# Show Motion stream on multiple web page

Tags: debian, webserver, camera, motion

I am running motion, and so far everything work nicely, I can access the stream on port 8081, without problem.

Is there a way to show the stream of the same webcam on multiple port ? If yes, how ? I tried setting up this in `motion.conf` :

```
stream_port 8081
stream_port 8082
```

But only the last port is reachable. How can both be reachable ?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy actually:
Just copy the code available at myIP:8081 and put it on the webpages you want it to be shown.
The code is:

```
<img class="shrinkToFit" alt="http://myIP:8081/" src="http://myIP:8081/" height="236" width="288">
```

And the image will be displayed properly.